# xslt how to select either the current node or a preceding sibling but not both

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

So I have xml that look like this

```
<Data>
    <History>
        <z r="1" c1="BILL" c2="123" c3="02/20/2006" c4="100.00" c5=".00" c6=".00" c7="100.00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="BILL"/>
        <z r="2" c1="PAYCODE" c2="456" c3="03/16/2006" c4="-100.00" c5=".00" c6=".00" c7="-100.00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="PAYMENT"/>
        <z r="3" c1="Total" c2="123" c3="02/20/2006" c4=".00" c5=".00" c6=".00" c7=".00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="Total"/>
        <z r="4" lcdesc=""/>
        <z r="5" c1="BILL" c2="124" c3="03/27/2006" c4="13000.00" c5="400.00" c6=".00" c7="13400.00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="BILL"/>
        <z r="6" c1="PAYCODE" c2="457" c3="04/13/2006" c4="-13000.00" c5="-400.00" c6=".00" c7="-13400.00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="PAYMENT"/>
        <z r="7" c1="Total" c2="124" c3="03/27/2006" c4=".00" c5=".00" c6=".00" c7=".00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="Total"/>
        <z r="8" lcdesc=""/>
        <z r="9" c1="BILL" c2="125" c3="04/28/2006" c4="1000.00" c5=".00" c6=".00" c7="1000.00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="BILL"/>
        <z r="10" c1="PAYCODE" c2="458" c3="05/10/2006" c4="-1000.00" c5=".00" c6=".00" c7="-1000.00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="PAYMENT"/>
        <z r="11" c1="Total" c2="125" c3="04/28/2006" c4=".00" c5=".00" c6=".00" c7=".00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="Total"/>
        <z r="12" lcdesc=""/>
   </History>
</Data>
```

And I want to put some information from the c1="BILL" z node on the subsequent lines.  I want to get the invoice number (c2) and the invoice date (c3).  So I figured in my template I'd declare a variable and do a select for either the current node if c1 = 'BILL' or the preceding-sibling where c1 = 'BILL'.  While it works for the first node and it's subsequent lines, on the second bill line it puts the previous bill lines information.  So something isn't right.  Can you help?

Here is my non-working xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="*|/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()|@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:output indent="no"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
<History>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//History/z"/>
</History>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="/PageData/History/z">
<xsl:variable name="invnode" select="current()[@c1 = 'BILL'] | preceding-sibling::z[@c1 = 'BILL'][1]" />
        <z>
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <!--get the attribute name-->
                <xsl:variable name="nodename">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:attribute name="{$nodename}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:attribute name="invoice"><xsl:value-of select="$invnode/@c2" /></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:if test="string-length($invnode/@c3) >= 10">
                                <xsl:attribute name="invdate1"><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($invnode/@c3, 7), substring($invnode/@c3, 1, 2), substring($invnode/@c3, 4, 2))" /></xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:attribute name="invdate2"><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($invnode/@c3, 7), '-', substring($invnode/@c3, 1, 2), '-', substring($invnode/@c3, 4, 2))" /></xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
        </z>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I want is as follows:

```
<Data>
   <History>
      <z r="1" c1="BILL" c2="123" c3="02/20/2006" c4="100.00" c5=".00" c6=".00" c7="100.00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="BILL" invoice="123" invdate1="20060220" invdate2="2006-02-20" />
      <z r="2" c1="PAYCODE" c2="456" c3="03/16/2006" c4="-100.00" c5=".00" c6=".00" c7="-100.00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="PAYMENT"  invoice="123" invdate1="20060220" invdate2="2006-02-20" />
      <z r="3" c1="Total" c2="123" c3="02/20/2006" c4=".00" c5=".00" c6=".00" c7=".00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="Total" invoice="123" invdate1="20060220" invdate2="2006-02-20" />
      <z r="4" lcdesc="" invoice="123" invdate1="20060220" invdate2="2006-02-20" />
      <z r="5" c1="BILL" c2="124" c3="03/27/2006" c4="13000.00" c5="400.00" c6=".00" c7="13400.00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="BILL"  invoice="124" invdate1="20060327" invdate2="2006-03-27" />
      <z r="6" c1="PAYCODE" c2="457" c3="04/13/2006" c4="-13000.00" c5="-400.00" c6=".00" c7="-13400.00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="PAYMENT" invoice="124" invdate1="20060327" invdate2="2006-03-27" />
      <z r="7" c1="Total" c2="124" c3="03/27/2006" c4=".00" c5=".00" c6=".00" c7=".00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="Total" invoice="124" invdate1="20060327" invdate2="2006-03-27" />
      <z r="8" lcdesc="" invoice="124" invdate1="20060327" invdate2="2006-03-27" />
      <z r="9" c1="BILL" c2="125" c3="04/28/2006" c4="1000.00" c5=".00" c6=".00" c7="1000.00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="BILL" invoice="125" invdate1="20060428" invdate2="2006-04-28" />
      <z r="10" c1="PAYCODE" c2="458" c3="05/10/2006" c4="-1000.00" c5=".00" c6=".00" c7="-1000.00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="PAYMENT" invoice="125" invdate1="20060428" invdate2="2006-04-28" />
      <z r="11" c1="Total" c2="125" c3="04/28/2006" c4=".00" c5=".00" c6=".00" c7=".00" c8=".00" c9=".00" c10=".00" lcdesc="Total" invoice="125" invdate1="20060428" invdate2="2006-04-28" />
      <z r="12" lcdesc="" invoice="125" invdate1="20060428" invdate2="2006-04-28" />
   </History>
</Data>
```

Comment: I can't figure out from your description what is it that you are actually trying to accomplish. Could you at least post the expected result of transforming your example input?

Comment: I added the expected output as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="z">
    <xsl:variable name="invnode" select="current()[@c1='BILL'] | preceding-sibling::z[@c1 = 'BILL'][1][not(current()/@c1='BILL')]" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="invoice">
            <xsl:value-of select="$invnode/@c2" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="invdate1">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($invnode/@c3, 7), substring($invnode/@c3, 1, 2), substring($invnode/@c3, 4, 2))" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="invdate2">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($invnode/@c3, 7), '-', substring($invnode/@c3, 1, 2), '-', substring($invnode/@c3, 4, 2))" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Explanation:**

This expression:

```
current()[@c1='BILL']
```

selects the current node, **provided that the current node is an invoice**; otherwise it returns an empty node-set.

This expression:

```
preceding-sibling::z[@c1 = 'BILL'][1][not(current()/@c1='BILL')]"
```

returns the nearest preceding-sibling that is an invoice, **provided that the current node is not an invoice**; otherwise it returns an empty node-set.

Therefore, in the union of these two expressions, one of the sub-sets will always be empty:

- If the current node is an invoice, the left-hand side returns the current node, and the right-hand side is empty.
- If the current node is not an invoice, the left-hand side is empty, and the right-hand side returns the nearest preceding-sibling that is an invoice.

Thus the union will only ever contain a single node, and the order is of no significance.

Comment: That works but I'm not sure why.  Does preceding-sibling match the current node? That wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @WillRickards It works because the two paths are mutually exclusive, and the union will only ever contain one node. IOW, it's an XOR selection.

Comment: That is true only if preceding-sibling is including the current node.  Otherwise it would have the current node from the first node-set and the first preceding sibling z BILL node from the second node set.  I think what is happening is the order of the nodes in the union isn't matching the xpath expression order and something with that criteria is forcing it to the expected order.

Comment: Based on the other answer the union nodes being in document order makes more sense.  So the first such node in the union nodeset is actually the preceding sibling, not the current node, causing the issue.  Which makes me even more curious as to how this one is working!

Comment: @WillRickards I have added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, this makes it clear why it works.  I learned a few things today.

Answer (score 2):

How about ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0" >
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="z">
  <z invoice="{(.|preceding-sibling::z)[@c1='BILL'][last()]/@c2}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="(.|preceding-sibling::z)[@c1='BILL'][last()]/@c3" mode="inv-date" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </z>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@c3" mode="inv-date" />

<xsl:template match="@c3[string-length(.) &gt;= 10]" mode="inv-date">
  <xsl:attribute name="invdate1"><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 7),      substring(., 1, 2),      substring(., 4, 2))" /></xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="invdate2"><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 7), '-', substring(., 1, 2), '-', substring(., 4, 2))" /></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I like the xpath expression in this one because of the last().  But how are you assured the order of that union is in document order?

Comment: Because that is the definition of what `|` does. It is *not* just a union operator. It unions, de-dups and sorts in document order. The grouping brackets will also sort in document order.

Comment: Did you want the string length test for `@c3`? You put it in your trial solution, but you accepted Michael's solution which did not include the test.

Comment: That is sort of extraneous to the crux of the problem which was how to get the exclusive or type treatment for invnode.  I accepted his because it provided a solution and has an effective explanation.  I liked your solution too but I thought his was closer to the desired effect.  I do need the test for string-length in my actual solution as there are some without dates.